# Rails: finding database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In order to improve my understanding of Rails, I'm converting a Sinatra app that uses data_mapper.

I'm trying to find the best replacements for data mappers  'first' method that searches database and returns first instance of the record sought.

Can anyone comment if this is done right, or if there's a better solution?

**Situation #1**
Sinatra

```
url = Url.first(:original => original)
```

Rails (both of these ok?)

```
url = Url.find_by_original(original) #this  find_by_original
url = Url.where(:first_name => 'original')
```

**situation #2**

Sinatra

```
raise 'Someone has already taken this custom URL, sorry' unless Link.first(:identifier => custom).nil?
```

My Rails  (with find)

```
raise 'Someone has already taken this custom URL, sorry' unless Link.find(:identifier => custom).nil?  #this  Link.find
```

Original context was a method that shortens urls

```
def self.shorten(original, custom=nil)
    url = Url.first(:original => original) 
    return url.link if url    
    link = nil
    if custom
      raise 'Someone has already taken this custom URL, sorry' unless Link.first(:identifier => custom).nil?
      raise 'This custom URL is not allowed because of profanity' if DIRTY_WORDS.include? custom
      transaction do |txn|
        link = Link.new(:identifier => custom)
        link.url = Url.create(:original => original)
        link.save        
      end
    else
      transaction do |txn|
        link = create_link(original)
      end    
    end
    return link
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a validator on the model. Just do a `validates_uniqueness_of :first_name` in the Url model (app/models/url.rb). There are also other validations available in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers)

*EDIT*

If you really want to find if such a record exists manually. You can just do `Url.find(:first, :conditions => { :first_name => 'original' })` and check for nil

```
raise 'Someone has already taken this custom URL, sorry' unless Link.find(:first, :conditions => { :identifier => custom }).nil?
```

Also, if you are new to rails might want to look at the [query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). Personally, I like to use the [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem so my queries are strictly ruby instead of mixing ruby and sql statements.

Comment: but that's not the purpose of the code. The code I put in the OP is just one part of a method that shortens urls. I'll put the whole original method in the OP.

Comment: Actually looking at it, the way you did it is fine. You can write it how I wrote it, write it using a where.limit or you can call the find_by_column method. It's up to you really

Comment: The Model.find(:first), Model.find(:all) methods are Rails 2 so you should upgrade them to the chained ways Model.all, Model.first, etc if you are going to be using or upgrading to Rails 4